# Installing Hg-Git on Windows 7 64bit

Tags: git, mercurial-extension, hg-git

I am trying for a while installing [Hg-Git addon](http://hg-git.github.com/) to my Windows 7 Operating system

1. I have crossed several difficulties like installing Python and other utilities described in [this blog](http://blog.sadphaeton.com/2009/01/20/python-development-windows-part-2-installing-easyinstallcould-be-easier.html).
2. I had even after this manual problems and could not install this addon because of errors described in [this log](http://pastebin.com/C3i1hMJB).
3. I searched google and I have found [this manual](http://blog.nlift.com/2009/06/python-on-windows-c-extensions-and.html)
4. Now i have these errors showed in [this log](http://pastebin.com/iQYp4n5C).

Any help with these errors? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ok i got it so ... For others - you need to clone this repo

**HTTPS:**

```
git clone https://github.com/jelmer/dulwich.git
```

**SSH:**

```
git clone git@github.com:jelmer/dulwich.git
```

or just download source - after that you need to go to its folder when you downloaded in command line type:

```
python setup.py install
```

You are done after you can simply do:

```
easy_install hg-git
```

On windows and make it work - so congratulations :-) Close.

Comment: 'easy_install' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: You will need Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler for Python 2.7 is not installed already.

Answer (score 26):

In case it helps anyone, I have Windows 7 64bit and TortoiseHg and following their [instructions](http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/manual/1.0/nonhg.html#hg-git-git) was easy and worked without issue.

> **Installation**
>
> TortoiseHg Windows installers come with the python-git bindings (named
>   dulwich) that hg-git requires, so one only needs to clone the hg-git
>   repository to your local computer:
>
> `hg clone http://bitbucket.org/durin42/hg-git/ C:\hg-git`
>
> Then enable
>   hggit and bookmarks in your Mercurial.ini file:
>
> `[extensions]`
>
> `bookmarks =`
>
> `hggit = C:\hg-git\hggit`
>
> You can verify that
>   worked by typing hg help hggit

Comment: You can find `Mercurial.ini` file in `%USERPROFILE%` folder.

Comment: Hg-Git has moved location (since BitBucket deleted all their users Hg repos!) - try this instead: `hg clone https://foss.heptapod.net/mercurial/hg-git C:\hg-git`

Answer (score 0):

I created a powershell script which does the installation in one step. The prereq is you have some build tools and python already installed: 
http://ig2600.blogspot.com/2013/02/using-git-via-hg-on-windows.html